# The number of $k$-surjective functions

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X,Y$ be two finite sets such that $|X| \geq k|Y|$ for some positive integer $k$. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective function, we say $f$ is $k$-surjective if for all $y\in Y$ we have $|f^{-1}(y)|\geq k$, so each $y$ has at least $k$ preimages. In particular a surjective function is $1$-surjective.

Let $|X|=n$ where $n\geq k|Y|$, then how to find the number of $k$-surjective functions? We know that in general for any $|X|\geq |Y|$, the number of surjective functions from $X$ to $Y$ is given by the Stirling's number of the second kind, which is $$|Y|!S(|X|,|Y|) $$ so I would expect this Stirling's number also appears.

Comment: Those are Associated Stirling numbers of the second kind. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind